# Javascript find predetermined frequency from sound

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to make a music visualizer that uses a musical note scale for which frequencies to find. If I try to use a conventional FFT, I end up with all of the bass notes that SHOULD be separate winding up on the same bar, which screws up the visualization.

Is there a way that I can get an array of the audio samples, get direct frequency data from an MP3 file, or an analysis API that lets me calculate for a specific frequency?

P.S. As the title says, I'm working in Javascript.

Comment: Your best (and probably only) bet is the [Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Comment: I see. The ScriptProcessor node seems useful (despite its imminent depreciation). Thanks! By the way, would you recommend a custom FFT or another algorithm?